# How to properly add image (atomic) without 2 empty lines in Draft.js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

By default draft.js puts any atomic type block with 2 empty lines (1 before atimic, 1 after atimic). This behavior is a result of lack atomic selection in draft.js and descripted [here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/327). How can i rid those lines ? i haven't found any proper function in Modifier. 
Maybe some one has another solution to solve this issue cuz right now it doesn't looks nice

UPDATE: i find sollution that works for me:

```
      const { editorState } = this.props;
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
      const entityKey = Entity.create('image', 'IMMUTABLE', {src: this.state.url});
      const with_atomic = AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(editorState, entityKey, ' ');
      const new_content_state = with_atomic.getCurrentContent();
      const block_map = new_content_state.getBlockMap();
      const current_atomic_block = block_map.find(block => {
         if (block.getEntityAt(0) === entityKey) {
            return block
         }
      });
      const atomic_block_key = current_atomic_block.getKey();
      const block_before = new_content_state.getBlockBefore(atomic_block_key).getKey();
      const new_block_map = block_map.filter(block => {
         if ((block.getKey() !== block_before) ) {
            return block
         }
      });
      const newContentState = contentState.set('blockMap', new_block_map);
      const newEditorState = EditorState.createWithContent(newContentState);
      this.props.onChange(newEditorState);
```

Comment: insert a atomic `ContentBlock` to `ConentState.getBlockMap()` will not add these 2 empty lines.

Comment: Thank for ur answer, but can u tell more how to implement this ?
currently i do this
const contentState = this.props.editorState.getCurrentContent();
const entityKey = Entity.create('image', 'IMMUTABLE', {src: this.state.url}); this.props.onChange(AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(this.props.editorState, entityKey, ' '));
how can i modify this code according to use ur solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a couple lines of code if you need handle the non-collapsed selection when do the insertion. If you just need remove the two lines around the atomic, maybe this code working:

```
const newAtomicBlock = contentState.getBlockMap().find(b=>b.getEntityAt(0)===entityKey).getKey();
const newBlockMap = contentState.getBlockMap().delete(contentState.getBlockBefore(newAtomicBlock)).delete(contentState.getBlockAfter(newAtomicBlock));
const newContentState = contentState.set('blockMap', newBlockMap);
const newEditorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, 'delete-empty-lines');
```

Comment: Sorry for long answer. I finished implementation based on ur code cuz some methods didn't work. I update code in head of this topic. Thank u very much for ur solution